# How to test a function that updates state in a component with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Here is a snippet of my application

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchText:""
    };
  }

  handleSelectionInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({searchText:e.target.value});

  }
```

How do i test the handleSelectionInput.

Comment: when is `handleSelectionInput` called  in your component? how updating `this.state.searchText` affects rendering's result? in general, approach is really straightforward: you invoke some nested element's prop by `.simulate('click-or-what-event-you-need', eventMock)` and then check what has been updated in render's result

Comment: @skyboyer, its used as a callback for a child stateless component, Simulation is nice, but codecoverage does not affect the  this,setState part of the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, the issue was not to simulate but rather work with the instance of the wrapper as seen below

```
it("Test handleSelectionInput", () => {
expect(wrapper.state('searchText')).toBe("");
instance.handleSelectionInput({ target: { name: 'input', value: '02' } });
expect(wrapper.state('searchText')).toBe("02");
```

});

Comment: `wrapper is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using enzyme. check below example where i did test onchange event

```
import React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Input from './Input';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test('Date with default date value handle click', () => {
  const component = shallow(
    <Input
      name="input"
      id="input"
      error
      pattern=".*"
      transformValue={value => value}
    />
  );
  expect(component.state().value).toEqual('');
  component.find('#input').simulate('change', { target: { name: 'input', value: '02' } });
  expect(component.state().value).toEqual('02');
  component.find('#input').simulate('blur', { target: { name: 'input', value: '02' } });
  expect(component.state().value).toEqual('02');
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep , although it did not entirely cover the situation,

Comment: ```render() {
    return (
      <div className="parentContainer">
        <h1>TODO APPLICATION</h1>
        <InputField name={"searchEngine"} value={this.state.searchText} callback={this.handleSelectionInput} />
        <ButtonField value="GO" />
      </div>
    ); ```  I have functional component that I am targetting, but the tests do not cover the callback function